# How do I "vectorize" calls to dpois?

Tags: r

I am not sure if this is an instance of vectorizing the operations in R, but this is where I am stuck:

I want to get:

```
dpois(1, 0.1)
dpois(2, 0.2)
dpois(3, 0.3)
```

and I tried:

```
dpois(1:3, 0.1:0.3)
```

and

```
do.call(dpois, list(x = 1:3, lambda = 0.1:0.3))
```

both do not work.

It there a R-ish way of doing this?

Comment: This isn't really about vectorizing calls to `dpois`. It's more a question about creating vectors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `help(dpois)` it looks like you need `x` and `lambda` to be vectors (read more about object classes in the R Intro or any other R documentation to understand what this means).

The following works:

`dpois(1:3, c(seq(0.1, 0.3, .1)))`

Your first attempt fails because you are not concatenating (see: `help(c)`) the values for `0.1:0.3` into a vector and you are not providing any way for R to know what you want it to do with `0.1:0.3`. Calling `seq()` in the manner above tells it to get a sequence from 0.1 to 0.3 by 0.1.

Your second attempt is pretty far into the weeds. There's no way you need a power-tool like `do.call` for this kind of thing.

Comment: I should have looked at this carefully.

Comment: no worries, glad I could answer the question.

Comment: The only problem is with the 0.1:0.3 part. `1:3` is already a vector and doesn't require concatenation.

Comment: indeed. edited accordingly.

Comment: A more compact version of the same answer: `dpois(1:3, 1:3/10)`.

Answer (score 1):

The `dpois` function is already a vectorised function --- it is already capable of taking vector inputs of `x` and `lambda`.  The problem is that your coding `0.1:0.3` does **not** produce the desired vector `c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3)`.  The following `R` code gives the same results as individual calls:

```
x      <- 1:3
lambda <- 1:3/10;

set.seed(1);
dpois(x, lambda);

[1] 0.090483742 0.016374615 0.003333682
```